# Get all int value in another int variable

Tags: variables, int

Suppose I have 4 int variable named a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4. Now how can I get all value in new int variable.

E=1234.

Answer (score 1):

What is the domain of your 4 variables {a, b, c, d} ?

One possible solution should be converting all the values to string, concatenating everything and converting to int again, but if you know that the values of your variables will stay in range [0, 9] you can just do
E = d + (c*10*) + (b*100) + (a*1000)